# How can i get the date and time from the datetime string in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, sql-order-by

```
id    user_id   created_at          status          amount
16924   4387 15-03-2019 15:33   bill created    149250
16925   4387 15-09-2019 15:47   bill created    444600
16926   4387 31-07-2019 15:31   bill created    879200
```

I want to sort the `created_at` column

The query I used for as below:

```
SELECT * FROM settlement ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, created_at,101);
```

Here `settlement` is my table name. After running the error I got as:

> ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'created_at,101) LIMIT 100' at line 2

Is there a way to get the sorted list?

Comment: Store dates using a date data type. Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

`CONVERT(...)` is SQL Server syntax, that is not supported in MySQL. You can use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) instead:

```
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(created_at, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i')
```

The second argument to `STR_TO_DATE()` is a format specifier. For your use case:

- `%d`: Day of the month, numeric (01..31)
- `%m`: Month, numeric (01..12)
- `%Y`: Year, numeric, four digits
- `%H`: Hour (00..23)
- `%i`: Minutes, numeric (00..59)

Side note: **fix your data model**! Storing dates as strings is the root of many evils. You will quickly end up converting the strings to dates again and again in your queries, which is error-prone and highly inefficient, since it prevents the database to take advantage of an existing index on the date column.

Comment: thanks worked but when i am trying for SELECT STR_TO_DATE('15-09-2019  15:47:00','%d,%m,%Y') as date; this gives a null result

Comment: @AbhipsaPatro: well, format specifier `'%d,%m,%Y'` does not match your input string, here it should be `'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s'`.

Answer (score 1):

`created_at`, should be a `datetime` type.

By doing so all SQL operations on it will not require special attention.

When you retrieve it you can use application code to display the date in US format. Alternative is to use [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Modification can be done with:

```
ALTER TABLE settlement ADD created_at_real DATETIME;
UPDATE settlement SET created_at_real = STR_TO_DATE(created_at, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i');
ALTER TABLE settlement DROP COLUMN created_at, RENAME COLUMN created_at_read TO created_at;
```

Then your query becomes:

```
select * from settlement ORDER BY created_at
```